# WordPress Underscores dropdown nav - fix submenus staying open when another is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, navigation

Working with the WordPRess Underscores theme, downloaded a few days ago.

Looking at the nav, the dropdown menus stay open unless you click it again to close it, when I need it to close if I click another dropdown.

The code for the toggle is as follows:

```
if ($(".main-header").length) {
    var mainHeader = $(".main-header"),
      mainHeaderHeight = mainHeader.height(),
      menuToggle = mainHeader.find(".menu-toggle"),
      mainMenuListWrapper = $(".main-menu > ul"),
      mainMenuListDropdown = $(".main-menu ul li:has(ul)");

    /* ========== Dropdown Menu Toggle ========== */
    menuToggle.on("click", function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("menu-open");
      mainMenuListWrapper.slideToggle(300);
    });

    mainMenuListDropdown.each(function () {
      $(this).append('<span class="dropdown-plus"></span>');
      $(this).addClass("dropdown_menu");
    });

    $(".dropdown-plus").on("click", function () {
      $(this).prev("ul").slideToggle(300);
      $(this).toggleClass("dropdown-open");
    });

    $(".dropdown_menu a").append("<span></span>");
  }
```

I've tried using a removeClass, .hide, etc but keep breaking it or nothing happening. I feel like this can't be that hard but my lack of js/jquery fundamentals really showing here.

Site this is on:

https://dev-autograph.pantheonsite.io/ - if you click the "menu" in the top right, displays a full screen menu, and then click any of the menu items "Our Services" then click any other "Our Team" or "Our World" etc and you'll see the sub menus stay open and overlay each other. I just need them to close when another is clicked.

Let me know if that needs more clarification!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested the code but does something like this work in this specific case?

```
   $(".dropdown-plus").on("click", function () {
          $(this).prev("ul").slideToggle(300);
          $(this).toggleClass("dropdown-open");
          //add this line
          $(this).parents().siblings().children('.sub-menu').hide();
        });
```

The idea is to choose dropdown-plus parent which is li. Then choose it's siblings which is rest of li items. Choose sibling li child sub-menu and hide it. Let me know is something like this works for you.